# Error when trying to insert multiple records for account object with workbench

Tags: community

so I am trying to figure out the answer, but i have been stuck for about 7 hours now to no avail. I keep getting the error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY when i'm uplodaing multiple records to the accounts. I'm using a developer account because I don't have access to anything else. I've looked at my record types for all of the objects and they are blank. I am thinking this is the problem because the csv file i'm using has a RecordTypeId and when I look for that ID there is no Record type for that object. The developer edition has no record types for any objects. PLEASE HELP!!

Answer (score 1):

> I am thinking this is the problem because the csv file i'm using has a RecordTypeId and when I look for that ID there is no Record type for that object

That's a pretty good guess. It may not be the only problem, but it's certainly *a* problem if that column contains non-empty values and your org has no Record Types. A Record Type Id is a cross-reference to a different object (the `RecordType` object), and it sounds like all of yours are invalid.

Generally, Salesforce data is likely to be in some way *org-dependent*. It may contain references to custom fields and objects, to Record Type Ids, which are specific to one org and its sandboxes, reference User Ids, and so on down the line. If you're trying to import data that came out of one org into another, you're likely going to need to some massaging to remove the elements of your data set that are dependent on its original home before you load the data into a new org.

If you don't need the Record Type data, just delete it. If you do need the Record Type data, there's something else problematic about the definition of your project, because this won't work as described.

Comment: yeah, so  I deleted the ownerID and RecordTypeID from the csv file and it worked. My only question is, I wonder if those 2 fields are needed? This was a take home assignment for a potential job. It was to upload the 4 test accounts using workbench. I'm just not sure if I needed those accounts, but then again, wouldn't i need to have access to their org to upload the records based on recordtypeID and OwnerID since those IDs are not part of my org.

Comment: You would never be able to upload data with populated RecordTypeId and OwnerId unless you were also provided an org that contains data matching those ids in the RecordType and User objects. So yes, I think you are correct.